# how to use getItemAtPosition in my spinner from firebase in google map using android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, direction, data-retrieval

I need help. Here i have load the hospital name from firebase to spinner how i want to getItemAtposition because when i click on hospital name it has to seleceted and clicked on getDirection button in my application so it will reload to the google map and mark on particular hospital which is selected so now how can do in my java code,  but i know missing something but cant find me please help me out 
Thanks in advance

```
Java code 

//init Db
        hospitalRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("hospital");
        //init interface
        iFirebaseLoaddone = this;

        hospitalRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                List<Hospital> hospital = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot hospitalsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    hospital.add(hospitalsnapshot.getValue(Hospital.class));
                }
                iFirebaseLoaddone.onFirebaseLoadSuccess(hospital);

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                iFirebaseLoaddone.onFirebaseLoadFailed(databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });

        searchableSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String seleceted =parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Log.e("clicked",""+ seleceted);


                hospitalRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                        setMarker(dataSnapshot);

                      //  Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                        setMarker(dataSnapshot);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }


                });
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

```
 @Override
    public void onFirebaseLoadSuccess(List<Hospital> hospitalList) {

        hospitals = hospitalList;

        //get all data
        List<String> id = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> name_list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> latitude = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> longitude = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Hospital hospital : hospitalList)
            // id.add(hospital.getId());
            name_list.add(hospital.getName());


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name_list);
        searchableSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get **selected value** from **spinner** as below,

```
String seleceted =parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); //your code
String selected = name_list.get(position); //another way to get selected name
```

You can get **latitude** and **longitude** from spinner - hospital name from **firebase** DB.

```
Query query = reference.orderByChild("name").equalTo(seleceted);
     query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                           double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue();
                           double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue();
                           setMarker(latitude,longitude);
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                       }
                   });
```

Comment: you said that another way of selecting name but that name load all the data from firebase like lat and long of that particular hospital name

Comment: here i have load latitude and longitude from firebase it is marking in my google map what i want is only name_list is loaded to spinner but when i click on hospital name in spinner it as to intent to google map and show that hospital name location in google map how can i do that